# Calculate user proximity to map marker

Tags: reactjs, gps, mapbox, mapbox-gl

What is an easy way to calculate a user's proximity to map marker, I tried using the following functions, but I don't think this is optimal.

```
  const userLatitudeIsWithinRadious = (collectible: any, userCords: any) =>
    collectible.latitude + 0.01 > userCords.latitude &&
    collectible.latitude - 0.01 < userCords.latitude;

  const userLongitudeIsWithinRadious = (collectible: any, userCords: any) =>
    collectible.longitude - 0.001 <=
    userCords.longitude >=
    collectible.longitude + 0.001
```

I'm using [react-map-gl](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/) as a React wrapper for [mapbox](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/), so I'm not sure if there's a specific solution somewhere in the documentations (haven't found it yet.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this npm package to get your answer

https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolocation-utils

get the user and map marker coordinates and pass them to "distanceTo()" method in "geolocation-utils" npm package and get the distance

distanceTo({lat: 51, lon: 4}, {lat: 51.0006, lon: 4.001})
// 96.7928594737802 meters

There are more methods that you can look into in this package

Comment: I managed to get it working with [turf.js](https://turfjs.org/), but this package is much easier and lighter haha. I got this working with `insideCircle`

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you.